# fetching image , Unauthorized access exception error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am fetching json data in which there is a link to again fetch an image

For example:

```
{"status":"403","message":"Not Authorized","image":"http:\/\/abc.com\/images\/1.jpg"}
```

status, message n image are retrieved perfectly fine as i displayed there value in a text box.

Further I wanted to display image so I do:

```
public string link = ClassName.variableName;
```

`link` now holds the value `http//abc.com/images/1.jpg`. I displayed its value in text box and its fine. So I moved further:

```
BitMapImage MyImage = new BitMapImage( new Uri (link, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

image1.source = MyImage;
```

But when I run it shows error "UnAuthorized access exception unhandled ". To cross check I opened a new project and instead of fetching the data, I directly provided a link into the image source and the image was displayed.

```
BitMapImage MyImage = new BitMapImage( new Uri ("http//abc.com/images/1.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

image1.source = MyImage;
```

Here it works fine. Image is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

i wasn't using Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => now it works fine.